# Docusign Target account not found while using JWT Auth

Tags: docusignapi

We are following Nodejs code repo from Docusign quick start examples and recently applied the App integration for go-live. The JWT Grant worked in Demo mode with our Admin user granting the consent but we have been facing trouble granting the consent in the Go-Live integration of the same App.
It keeps on error out with this message :

```
 Error: Target account 6fd8b7f2-54a4-453e-b120-xxxxxxxxxx not found!
    at _DsJwtAuth._getUserInfo [as getUserInfo] (D:\Docusign-node.js\lib\DSJwtAuth.js:138:15)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
    at async log (D:\Docusign-node.js\lib\DSJwtAuth.js:181:22)
(node:6624) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Target account 6fd8b7f2-54a4-453e-b120-XXXXXXXX not found!
    at _DsJwtAuth._getUserInfo [as getUserInfo] (D:\Docusign-node.js\lib\DSJwtAuth.js:138:15)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
    at async log (D:\Docusign-node.js\lib\DSJwtAuth.js:181:22)
```

We have added a user with just integration permissions to test this issue, with this user the JWT Grant works fine even in production but the issue is with the Admin user who have actually created the App integration is not able to grant the consent.
Looking for help!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! PLEASE check (accept) the best answer for each of your questions. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, your software is using /oauth/userinfo to check that the accountId is accessible by the user impersonated by the JWT Grant request. Is that right?

Check the reponse of the /oauth/userinfo API call for the admin user. If it does not include any accounts, or if no account is marked as the default account, then this is a problem that sometimes occurs in the DocuSign system.

To fix, you will need to contact Customer Support.

1. Login to the [Customer Support portal](https://support.docusign.com/en/contactSupport) (whether you have a support contract or not.) Use your `production` email and password.
2. Enter a new case. Include the output of the userinfo API call.

Comment: Thanks @Larry, thats exactly the issue we have been facing, the accounts of the impersonated user doesn't show up in the case of JWT Grant. 
exports {
  sub: '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000',
  email: 'null',
  accounts: [],
  givenName: 'null',
  familyName: 'null',
  created: '0001-01-01T00:00:00'
}.
We will contact the support. Thanks!!

Comment: See https://support.docusign.com/en/articles/Empty-UserInfo

Comment: Thansk @Larry, that was helpful. We have contacted the customer support regarding the issue. They quickly responded and resolved the issue. Thanks again!!